# Pointer passing Objective C or C syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I have a method , which takes the following argument.

```
void callAMethood(const void *iVar){}
```

now here i am not clear on how should i pointer

the following seems to be quite simple,where i just pass the address instead of  value.

```
NSString *a=@"Hi";
callAMethood(&a);
```

But, the following seems to work well, but understanding the syntax is difficult.

```
char const * const a="HI";
callAMethood(&a);
```

or even this works `callAMethood(a);`

Comment: both of them are wrong, why you think you need `&`?

Answer (score 4):

As xlc points out, both are wrong.

```
NSString *a=@"Hi";
callAMethood(&a); // This passes a NSString **


char const * const a="HI";
callAMethood(&a); // This passes a char const * const *
```

Both work, because a pointer to a pointer can stil be cast to a `void *`.

It is incredibly unlikely that you intended either, though.

Take advantage of C being type-checked at compile time and be more specific with your types.

```
void awesome_function(NSString *amazingString);

NSString *yay = @"oh my god yes";
awesome_function(yay); // ok
awesome_function(&yay); // compiler error
```

In short: unless you have a very good reason for using a `void *` (which I would consider unlikely for a Cocoa(Touch) app), don't.

If you don't want compile-time type checking, use something like Python.  If you want to be able to handle different Objective C object types, that's what `id` is for.

Answer (score 1):

You ask what you should pass to the *function* (it is not the declaration of a method):

```
void callAMethood(const void *iVar) {...}
```

**The answer is nobody can tell you!**

Your function takes a value of type `void *` - this type is typically used in C to mean a "pointer to *anything*". It is not a type that would be used for a function that took a pointer to any object, that would be `id`.

But that doesn't get us very far, as we've no idea what `callAMethood` is expecting we've no idea what to pass it - we cannot tell you the answer.

Now you give the example:

```
NSString *a = @"Hi";
callAMethood(&a);
```

That is a valid call, it passes a pointer to the variable `a`. However:

```
callAMethood(a);
```

is also a valid call, it passes the pointer which is stored in the variable `a`. Without any knowledge of what `callAMethood` is expecting we cannot tell you which is the correct call. The same applies to your second example.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Every pointer can be converted to `void *` implicitly.

**EDIT:**

1. As Kevin said, only **data** pointer.
2. As CRD said,

> > **The answer is nobody can tell you!**

without the information of the function of `callAMethood`. All of those invoking are valid grammatically(can be compiled), howerver, invalid semantically usually unless `callAMethood` really doesn't care about which type `iVar`(e.g. it just prints the pointer).

Answer (score 0):

What people said above is correct but you can also use UTF8String to get a const char * from a NSString

```
const char * myStr = [a UTF8string];
callMehtod(myStr);
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html